# Forgot password functionality - retrieve and mail - symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, password-recovery, forgot-password

I want to implement the forgot password functionality. I don't want to change the password. Rather I simply want to mail the password to the provided email address.

**But how can I get the decoded password and mail it to the email address?**

All I have got till now from SO and other links is the password change process. I don't want that. I can't find any example regarding this. I'm using following encoder:

```
algorithm:        sha512
encode_as_base64: true
iterations:       1
```

Please help...

Comment: you cant, its hashed, its not 'retrievable' -this is a VERY good thing

Comment: @Dagon I don't want to see the raw password. Isn't there any way that this will be handled by symfony?

Comment: if you don't want to see the raw password, what where you going to email the user?

Comment: You really shouldn't e-mail a password ever.  Unless of course you want to end up on this site :) http://plaintextoffenders.com/  Instead, code a password reset process.  E-mail them some long unique string that you store on their user record.  Something like yoursite.com/pwdreset.php?id=1234567890-1234567890-1234567890.... And make sure that ID becomes invalid after a day or after they reset it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer: You can't, and that is a VERY GOOD THING.**

*Hashes* apply one-way only transformations in order to protect the original password. This is to protect the security of the password in the case of a security breach (computationally costly operations are required to find a hash collision). This is a mathematical property of a hash (`sha512` is a hashing algorithm) and cannot be countered.

In fact, security auditors often verify that the reset password functionality of a website doesn't return the original password they set.

The only way to allow Symfony2 to do that would be to create your own encoder. [**However, not hashing your user's password would be a glaring security risk**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet).

I would also recommend you increase the amount of iterations used to hash the password (to strengthen the hash) and/or switch to `bcrypt`. A fast hash is a bad hash.